# Polymer Node to element attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes, polymer, core-elements

I have next polymer element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../lib/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="ss-timeline" attributes="musicChooser photoSelector">
    <template>
        <div></div>
    </template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            "use strict";

            Polymer('ss-timeline', {
                created: function(){
                    this.musicChooser = this.musicChooser || {};
                    this.photoSelector = this.photoSelector || {};
                },
                ready: function () {
                    console.log(this.musicChooser, this.photoSelector);
                },
                musicChooserChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
                    console.log('musicChooserChanged', oldVal, newVal);
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

So I have to pass into the **musicChooser** and **photoSelector** **Node objects** like so:

```
<ss-music-chooser id="musicChooser"></ss-music-chooser>
<ss-timeline musicChooser="{{$.musicChooser}}"></ss-timeline>
```

But in console output I get:

```
Object {} Object {}
```

How can I pass Node objects by the attributes? Please help.

P.S. I saw that core-dropdown has same **relatedTarget** attribute:

```
<core-icon-button id="trigger" icon="menu"></core-icon-button>
<core-dropdown relatedTarget="{{$.trigger}}">
  <core-menu>
    <core-item>Cut</core-item>
    <core-item>Copy</core-item>
    <core-item>Paste</core-item>
  </core-menu>
</core-dropdown>
```

So this should work in theory...

P.P.S. By the way if I pass in attribute musicChooser="123" I get it in my element. But node object ignored for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your changed watcher should work, [here's an example](http://jsbin.com/lisume/5/edit).

I'm wondering if the issue has to do with your use of [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding). The `$` is only going to work inside of another Polymer element (and possibly also inside of an auto-binding template, but I'd need to double check).